# Docking electron window on top of browsers and other applications

Tags: javascript, electron, toolbar, desktop-application

I have asked this question on a number of different forums and have not been able to find a solution. Can ANYONE tell me if this can be done?

When launched my Browserwindow currently sits on top of every other application that's running and is placed at the top of my screen which is what i want. However i also want the browser window to **SIT ABOVE** other applications. google chrome and other browsers such as Microsoft edge should sit below the electron app.

I've looked at discussions online and apparently this is doable on macOs, however no ones really said for definite if this can be done on windows devices or not.

Heres my code:

```js
const createWindow = () => {
    // Create the browser window.
    const mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({
        width: 1920,
        height: 200,
        alwaysOnTop:true,
        titleBarStyle: 'none',
        frame: false,
        resizable: false,
        minimizable: false,
        type: 'toolbar',
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation: false}
        });
  
    mainWindow.setAlwaysOnTop(true, "screen-saver");
    mainWindow.setVisibleOnAllWorkspaces(true);
    mainWindow.setMenuBarVisibility(false);
    mainWindow.moveTop();
    mainWindow.setPosition(0,0)
    // and load the index.html of the app.
    mainWindow.loadFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
```

Does anyone have a solution for this?

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not believe that this is natively possible on Windows and Linux OS machines using Electron and Node.js alone.

I believe you will need to write a C++ script that can query the OS windows that are open. Then by communicating back and forth between the C++ script and Electron, your Electron application can then become 'aware' of the position of the other windows. Then, though your C++ script, set the position and size of the other window(s) to snap to the bottom of your Electron application window.

Comment: thanks for the response! I was wondering what if I were to use Blazor and electron? I've seen a few videos online where people have integrated both together. Would i be able to dock the toolbar using Blazor? or would writing a C++ script be the best way?

Comment: I'm not familiar with Blazor (or Blazor WebAssembly) but it does look interesting. I cannot see why you couldn’t achieve the same outcome with Blazor (which uses C# over C++), but only in a Windows OS environment if I am not mistaken. If you can detect which window(s) are open on the same screen Electron is using (assuming there are multiple screens), get their rectangle bounds (x, y, width, height) and update / minimise them if needed to dock to your Electron window then great. Creating a carefully crafted C++ script would give you cross platform compatibility if needed though.